# array to string on PDO insert

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array, which includes an insertId (as a key) several other values; this needs to be submitted as a $key=> $value array (e.g. 1 => 2, 1 =>3, 1=>5) etc.

However, when I bind the parameters within the foreach loop, I keep getting an array to string conversion error.  as a result I get one row being inserted into the db (the correct key,and then a 0).

```
function instructorSubject()
{

    $query = "INSERT into instructor_has_subject
            SET instructor_id =  :instructor_id,
            subject_id = :id";

    $last_id = $this->conn->lastInsertId(); 


    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    //print_r($last_id);

    //print_r($this->id);
    if (isset($this->id) && $this->id != '') {
        foreach ($_POST as $values) {
            $stmt->bindParam(":instructor_id", $last_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(":id", $this->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        }

        if($stmt->execute())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            var_dump($stmt);
            print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

A sample array is something like this:
the insert id:  87
and then the second array appearing as a straight forward key=>value pair (for example:)
 ( [0] => 1 [1] => 3 )

I feel it has something to do with where I'm binding within the foreach.  thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: i dont understand your foreach, you never use `$values`

Comment: Note you don't actually need `bindParam` at all. You can pass the variables to `execute()` contained in an array. Take a look at my PDO class [GrumpyPDO](https://github.com/GrumpyCrouton/GrumpyPDO/blob/master/grumpypdo.php#49), specifically the `multi()` method (starting line 39), you can see you are supposed to loop over the `execute()`, NOT the `bindParam()`.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton  shouldn't I always bind variables?  My understanding is that if not it gets left open for sql injection? Or am I missing something?  I'll take a look at your class.   @nogad thanks for that suggestion;  I did switch it to `foreach ($_POST as $this->id)` and that got rid of the array to conversion error, but unfortunately it did not fix the insert

Comment: @nomistic You should _always_ used prepared statements with parameterized queries. What I was saying is that you can skip `bindParam()` and pass the variables directly through `execute()`. It's just less lines of code, easier to read, but does the exact same thing. You're just not supposed to concatenate directly into queries, if you are writing variables directly into a query you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @nomistic For example; instead of using `bindParam()`, you just pass the variables as an array to `execute()`, like this `$stmt->execute(array("instructor_id" => $last_id, "id" => $this->id))`. -- there are a couple other options here too. You don't really need "named parameters". If you replace `:instructor_id` and `:id` in your query with just a single question mark, you can pass the variables to execute like this: `execute([$lastid, $this->id]);`

Comment: ok, within the foreach loop?

Comment: @nomistic Yes. If you click "GrumpyPDO" (or just click [this link](https://github.com/GrumpyCrouton/GrumpyPDO/blob/master/grumpypdo.php#49)) in my first comment it will take you to the source code of my class, you can see how I loop over the `execute()` function.

Comment: tried this but now I'm back to the array to string conversion error:
   `foreach ($_POST as $this->id) {

    
    $stmt->execute(array("instructor_id" => $last_id, "id" => $this->id));
   }`

Comment: I tried the question mark approach, but still the same problem :/

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton the var_dump of stmt shows `PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => INSERT into instructor_has_subject SET instructor_id = ?, subject_id = ? ) ` (this actually hasn't changed).  I feel like there's something else I'm missing

Comment: @nomistic What response are you expecting? An insert doesn't return any rows.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton what I meant was that there were no rows inserted.  before I was able to get one dummy row with the insert id, but with only a 0 for $this->id.  At this point I'm getting nothing except the  array to string conversion error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160971/discussion-between-grumpycrouton-and-nomistic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After speaking to you in chat, this is the solution we came up with.

```
function instructorSubject()
{

    $query = "INSERT INTO instructor_has_subject (instructor_id, subject_id) VALUES (?,?)";

    $last_id = $this->conn->lastInsertId();

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    if(!empty($this->id)) {
        foreach($_POST['subject_id'] as $id) {                
            $stmt->execute(array(
                $last_id,
                $id
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

The main thing we changed I believe was changing `$_POST` to `$_POST['subject_id']`.

We also removed `bindParam` completely from the function, instead opting for unnamed parameters and passing the variables via `execute()` inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks a ton.  I appreciate the extra time you took

Comment: @nomistic No problem.